# Should I vote to reopen a closed question so I can close it as a duplicate instead?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm just asking generally, but for example, [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672656/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically) (currently closed as off-topic) looks like it could be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php) to me.

If it should stay closed for the original reason, is there a good way to link it to the possible duplicate? Just comment? Is it even worthwhile? Can a gold badge holder do this type of thing without other voters?

Comment: Have I asked enough questions in this question?

Comment: Yes, close-voting as too broad ;)